# @RestController bean registered in root context, despite being excluded in excludeFilters

Tags: java, spring, rest

So I've used Java Based Config to boot start the tomcat container, and creating the spring context. This is how my configuration classes look like:

```
@Configuration
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebAppInitializer.class);

  @Override
  public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    LOGGER.debug("Starting Spring Container");
    WebApplicationContext rootContext = createRootContext(servletContext);
    configureSpringMvc(servletContext, rootContext);
  }

  private WebApplicationContext createRootContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
    LOGGER.debug("Creating Root Context");
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(RootConfig.class);

    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
    LOGGER.debug("Created Root Context");
    return rootContext;
  }

  private void configureSpringMvc(ServletContext servletContext, WebApplicationContext rootContext) {
    LOGGER.debug("Creating Child Context");
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext mvcContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    mvcContext.register(WebMvcConfig.class);
    mvcContext.setParent(rootContext);

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic appServlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(mvcContext));
    FilterRegistration.Dynamic authFilter = servletContext.addFilter("authFilter", AuthenticationFilter.class);
    authFilter.addMappingForServletNames(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST), true, "dispatcher");
    appServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    appServlet.addMapping("/");
    LOGGER.debug("Created Child Context");
  }
}
```

As you can see, `RootConfig.class` makes up my root application context, and `WebMvcConfig` makes up the child application context.

Those classes look like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "a.b.controller" })
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
}

@Configuration
@Import(value = { PropertiesConfig.class, AppConfig.class })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "a.b", excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = RestController.class))
public class RootConfig {
}
```

Notice the `@ComponentScan` on both the classes. Package `a.b.controller` contains my `@RestController`s. I would like them to be initialized only in the child context.

So in my root context, I've excluded the `@RestController` annotated class from component scanning.  So I guess those controllers should not be registered there. However, this is not happening. All my rest controllers are getting registered in the root context, and then in the child context (which overrides the one in root context).

I'm unsure of why this is happening, and out of luck to get it resolved. I don't have any *web.xml* in my application, as everything is taken care by java config. This is one issue.

Second issue is, even though the RestController is registered twice, I am unable to resolve the `@Value` annotated property in those controllers when it is loaded in child context. But while loaded from root context, the properties are getting resolved.

Here's an example:

```
@RestController
public class PropertyLessController {

  @Value("${prop1}")
  private String prop1;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    LOGGER.debug("Property loaded: {}", prop1);
  }
}
```

I'm logging the property in the `init()` method. That log comes up twice:

```
Property loaded: someActualValue
Property loaded: @{prop1}
```

First one is from root context (with resolved property), and second one is from child context (with unresolved property). Now why is this happening?

I'm using *Spring 4.1.0.RELEASE*.

Comment: In what package is your `WebMvcConfig`?

Comment: `WebMvcConfig` and `RootConfig` both are in package `a.b.config`

Comment: Your `RootConfig` is also picking up the `WebMvcConfig` which in turn scans for the remainder of your classes, due to the additional `@ComponentScan`. `@Configuration` classes are also `@Component`s.

Comment: @M.Deinum O Dear!!! That completely passed under my head without getting even noticed.. Forgot that `@Configuration` classes are also components. Thanks for that. I guess then separating the two context in different packages should solve the issue?

Comment: @M.Deinum But what about the answer given below? That thing still persists? As excludeFilters won't work.

Comment: @M.Deinum And what should be the general approach? Keeping Root context and Child context config classes in separate packages?

Comment: Yes they work, you should exclude `@Configuration` classes as well as your `@RestController` (or you would probably want to exclude `@Controller` instead). However I still would package them seperately looking at what you have now I suspect you are packaging by type (service, repository, etc) instead of packaging by feature/functionality. (Technical instead of functional).

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes, I'm packaging based on layers, rather than functionality.

Comment: I was looking for an earlier answer of my regarding packaging/structuring. Found it [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/258196/java-application-structure-horizontal-vs-vertical-split/258197#258197).

Comment: @M.Deinum You sir are awesome!! Adding `@Configuration` annotation to the `excludeFilters` worked just perfect. And yes, that answer is enlightening. Thanks. Never thought of separating the packages like that. Basically since we divide the functionality in maven modules, and use maven dependency to restrict exposure to outside world, so internal of each maven module, we follow a technical package layering. Can I say that, this kind is somewhat on the lines of what you explained in your answer?

Comment: @M.Deinum Can you please add that as an answer, so I can accept it? BTW, I ended up removing the `@ComponentScan` on `a.b` package. As the scan seemed too broad. Rather splitted it in to different modules at layer level, with respective subpackages - `a.b.service`, `a.b.domain`, so that `a.b.controller` doesn't even get included. Gives more control. But your solution worked fine as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `@ComponentScan` of your `RootConfig`, although that excludes `@RestController` it scans the whole `a.b` package including all of its sub packages. Which in turn is also detecting the `WebMvcConfig` which in turn scans the `a.b.controller` package but doesn't exclude anything. Hence your controllers are instantiated twice, basically everything web related (also Spring @MVC) is loaded twice.

`@Configuration` is also a `@Component` and hence automatically detected. To fix it add an exclusion for `@Configuration` classes on your `RootConfig`.

```
@Configuration
@Import(value = { PropertiesConfig.class, AppConfig.class })
@ComponentScan( basePackages = "a.b", 
                excludeFilters = {
                    @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = RestController.class), 
                    @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Configuration.class})
public class RootConfig {}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is kind of tricky.

`@RestController` and `@Controller` are meta annotations. `@RestController` is annotated with `@Controller` and `@Controller` is annotated with `@Component`.

Through this *meta annotation* property, the component scan process finds your `PropertyLessController` type. It ignores it for `@RestController`, but it finds it for `@Controller` (or `@Component`) and then the handler mapping stack registers it because it finds `@Controller` and `@RequestMapping`.

A solution for that is to list `@Component` and `@Controller` in your `excludeFilters` or set `useDefaultFilters` to `false`. Obviously, this might not work for you since you probably have other types you want found with those annotations.

The "proper" solution is to package your things separately.

Regarding the property resolution. The `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` or `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` that you have configured (haven't seen your `PropertiesConfig`) is a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`. This type of processor only processes the beans in its containing `BeanFactory`. In other words, a child context's `BeanFactory` will not use a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` in a parent context (afaik). Since your `PropertiesConfig` is declared in your `RootConfig`, only the beans defined there will get property resolution.

You can put a breakpoint in your controller's `init` method. You'll notice that the value of the `@Value` annotated field is unresolved for the bean initialized in the `DispatcherServlet`'s context, the child context.

Comment: Well, adding `@Component` to excludeFilters will also exclude my other @Component annotated bean (as you said). But what exactly does `useDefaultFilters` will do? Package structure I know is screwed. basePackages should have been more granulated, but I'll keep changing that as my last option. Was looking for some easy work-around for now :(

Comment: I also tried the excludeFilter with regex, passing `a\\.b\\.controller\\..*` as my pattern. That also didn't work

Comment: @RohitJain `useDefaultFilters` dictates if all the default annotations `@Component`, `@Service`, `@Repository`, `@Controller` should be searched for. It's `true` by default. Setting it to `false` is more or less equivalent to listing the annotations in your `excludeFilters`.

Comment: So is there a way I can read the properties in my controller? I even tried `Environment#getProperty()` method, but that returns `null`.

Comment: @RohitJain Declare a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` in your child context too, with the appropriate property sources.

Comment: Thanks man!! Adding `@Import(PropertiesConfig.class)` also to `WebMvcConfig` did the trick. I don't really need to register separate PropertiesPlaceHolderConfigurer I guess.

Comment: @RohitJain It's kind of implicit. Doing that import creates a new `PropertiesConfig` instance (which I assume has a property resolver `@Bean`). This is separate instance from the one loaded by the `RootConfig`.

Comment: Yeah, and the one in Child context will override the bean in the root context, since the bean type is same right? I'm just testing this stuff, but will that in any case stop the properties from working with root context?

Comment: @RohitJain No overriding happens. Each bean is independently in its own `BeanFactory` in its `ApplicationContext`. The child `ApplicationContext` can refer to the beans in the parent `ApplicationContext`, but the `Bean[Factory]PostProcessor` only apply to the containing `BeanFactory`.

Comment: Thank you so much.. I tested, and it's working perfectly. And also `excludeFilters` worked too after excluding `@Configuration` annotation too. See the series of comments on the question. Thanks again. Learned so much in just single question :)